# Displaying a specific store from a list of store in MVC Store Locator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I am building a store locator for an online ordering service. I have a view and a controller. My view displays a list of stores based on a zip code search. from this list, you can click a button to place an order with that specific store. I have it linking to a new view where I want to display details about the specific store you selected. How can I do this?

```
<div class="store-list-box">
    @{
        foreach (var store in (List<Site>)ViewData["sites"])
        {

            <div class="store-list-style">
            <h3>@store.name</h3>
            <p>@store.address1</p>
            <p>@store.city, @store.state @store.zip</p>
            <p>@store.phone</p>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" onclick='window.location = "@Url.Action("StoreInfo", "OrderTime")";'>Place Order</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
        }

    }
</div>
```

This is the code I have where it displays the list of stores.

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
{
    List<Site> result = SiteMgmt.GetByZip(search);
    var emptyResult = new List<Site>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        View().ViewData["sites"] = emptyResult;
    }
    else
    {
        View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
    }
    return View();
}
```

This is the controller which displays the stores. On button click you go to the new view. How do I show the specific store details in that new view?

[This is a screenshot of the list I currently display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MStuw.png)

Here is the StoreInfor() code.

```
public class OrderTimeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult StoreInfo(int siteID)
    {
        Site result = SiteMgmt.GetSite(siteID);
        var emptyResult = new Site();
        if (siteID == 0)
        {
            View().ViewData["sites"] = emptyResult;
        }
        else
        {
            View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you click on the button within your `foreach` loop? And if so, show the signature of your `StoreInfo()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke Here is the code. public class OrderTimeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: OrderTime
        public ActionResult StoreInfo(int siteID)
        {

            Site result = SiteMgmt.GetSite(siteID);
            var emptyResult = new Site();
            if (siteID == 0)
            {
                View().ViewData["sites"] = emptyResult;
            }
            else
            {
                View().ViewData["sites"] = result;
            }

            return View();
        }
    }

Comment: You cdoe needs to go in the question, not comments

Comment: @StephenMuecke So sorry I put it in the question.

Comment: First, stop using `ViewData` and pass models to your view. `var result = new List<Site>(); if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search)) { result = SiteMgmt.GetByZip(search); } return View(result); }` and in the view `@model IEnumerable<Site>` and `foreach(var site in Model) { ...`

Comment: Then replace you button with `@Html.ActionLink("Place Order", "StoreInfo", "OrderTime", new { siteID = site.SiteId }, new { @class = "btn" })` (assumes `Site` has a property named `SiteId`)